# Windows 10 laptop reboots instead of waking from sleep when the system’s lid is open

Tags: windows-10

So, I have this issue with a users workstation: It’s a Dell 5520 running Windows 10.

When it's configured for sleep mode and the lid is closed then opened it reboots. No unexpected crash prompts from Windows when loading up. In hibernation mode it seems like it's working fine.

I updated the Intel Management Engine driver because they usually cause an issue like this, but the PC usually just shuts down not restart. I turned off the power saving mode off as well in the engine.

Comment: What events are logged in the System event log when you open the lid?

Comment: It was the end of the day when I was looking at it. I'll check in the morning and let you know.  Thanks

Comment: So I went to reproduce the issue this morning.  So I can fresh event logs. I changed the mode from hibernation back to sleep and it was working normally today. So maybe it was the usual Intel management engine.  Not sure, but will update if I find anything.